# inserting a new document in the arrray of documents

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a new document to the following document having an outer key "User"

```js
{
  name:himani,
  User:[
    {
      _id:e25ffgf627627,
      Name:User1
    },
    {
      _id:fri2i2jhjh9098,
      Name:User2
    }
  ]
};
```

Below is my code in which I am trying to add a new document to already existing document. 
My code is:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/?safe=true");
SafeMode mode = new SafeMode(true);
SafeModeResult result = new SafeModeResult();
var db = server.GetDatabase("himani");
var coll = db.GetCollection("test");
BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
document.Add("name", "himani");
result = coll.Insert(document, mode);

BsonDocument nested = new BsonDocument();
nested.Add("1", "heena").Add("2", "divya");
BsonArray a = new BsonArray();
a.Add(2);
a.Add(5);
nested.Add("values", a);
document["3"] = new BsonArray().Add(BsonValue.Create(nested));
coll.Save(document);
var query = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("name", "himani"),
    Query.EQ("3.1", "heena")
);
var match = coll.FindOne(query);

var update = Update.AddToSet("3", new BsonDocument {{ "count", "2" }});
coll.Update(query, update);
```

I want to add a new document to the User array. I am doing this by above code but its not working.Please tell me the right way of doing it.

Comment: what i want to do is: I want to find a document having some outer key value and then add more documents to it.

Comment: But has what you tried so far not worked? Can you just show us what you have so far so we can point out where it might be wrong?

Comment: @jdi. I have pasted the code . now please tell me the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your document structure at all...  and the only "user" array I could find in here was a field called "3".  Your code does in fact work and appends a document into the "3" array.  The below is the result after running your code.  Perhaps you could be more clear as to what you want your document to look like after you have "appended" a user.

```js
{
  "_id":ObjectId("4fa7d965ce48f3216c52c6c7"),
  "name":"himani",
  "3":[
    {
      "1":"heena",
      "2":"divya",
      "values":[ 2, 5 ]
    },
    {
      "count":"2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think its really helpful for OPs to post mongodb questions using the `mongo` native javascript syntax, as opposed to client driver specific formats that can add a layer of obfuscation over the goal. Its good that you are answering in a JSON format. I agree that even with the OPs added code snippet, its still not clear what they want the document structure to be.